# Can I use JTA with microservices?

Tags: transactions, jax-rs, microservices, jta

I'm building an application which is not targeting full-profiles EE container.

There are only JAX-RS resource classes and JPA entity classes.

And the final application maybe deployed as spring boot or any other simple deployable platforms such as micro profile.

Which also means there is no EJBs.

Can I use `JTA` with it? Or should I use `RESOURCE_LOCAL`?

Say, can I do this?

```
@Path(...)
public class MyResource {

    @Transactional
    public Response create(...) {
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

or should I do this?

```
@Path(...)
public class MyResource {

    public Response create(...) {
        // start / commit
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Context
    private UserTransation userTransaction;
}
```

or should I do this?

```
@Path(...)
public class MyResource {

    public Response create(...) {
        entityManger.getTransaction();
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

or should I do with `@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory`?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Spring transaction manager?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Spring is just one of candidates of target deployment platform. I'm separating JAX-RS resource classes into an another module. Thanks.

Comment: What container supports JAX-RS out of the box anyway? Personally I'd go for option 1 and require downstream support it. Downstream repos can build JEE deployments or pull in enough spring jars to support it.